# If user is signed into a google account can user still face the "I'm not a robot" message?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

If you are signed into a google account, will you still get the "I'm not a robot message", or is there no other way to avoid it besides paid services. I am using the **Selenium** library in python.

Comment: you won't be signed into a google account (maybe? not actually sure about that there), also they use new CAPTCHA stuff that doesn't even ask anything, just looks at the behavior, if you want to do sth with google sites (or really any other site that has it), use their provided API

Answer (score 1):

### I'm not a robot reCAPTCHA

[image: Im_not_a_robot]

This is a challenging test to differentiate between humans and automated bots based on the response. reCAPTCHA is one of the CAPTCHA spam protection services bought by Google. Automated robots are the biggest headache for producing spams and consuming server resources which supposed to be utilized by real users. In order to avoid automated bots Google introduced [**No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA**](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html) API concept for website owners to protect their sites. Later to improve user experience, Google introduced [**invisible reCAPTCHA**](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/).

Invisible CAPTCHA helps to stop bots without showing ***I'm not a robot*** message to human users. But it does not work on many situation as the message will be still shown. For example, Google search page itself will show the ***I'm not a robot*** CAPTCHA message on certain circumstances when you enter the query and hit search button. You will be asked to prove you are a human by selecting the checkbox or selecting images based on the given hint.

When you do a real Google search and getting interrupted with ***I'm not a robot*** message will make you really embarrassed. Sometimes it will allow you with a simple click on the checkbox. Google will check the clicking position on the checkbox. Bots click exactly on the center of the checkbox while humans click somewhere on the box. This will help to decide Google whether the user is a human or bot. In the worst case, Google will completely stop you by showing the sorry page. The only option you have here is to wait and try later.

In the worst case, Google will completely stop you by showing the sorry page. The only option you have here is to wait and try later.

[image: we_are_sorry]

---

### Root cause of I'm not a robot reCAPTCHA message

Some of the main reasons of this error are as follows:

- When Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the Terms of Service. The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.
- This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests. A different computer using the same IP address may be responsible.
- Sometimes you may see this page if you are using advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly.

---

### Fixing I'm not a robot reCAPTCHA issue

If you are always getting interrupted then a couple of remediation steps are as follows:

- Stop using VPN.
- Avoid unknown proxy servers.
- Use Google public DNS.
- Stop searching illegal queries.
- Slow your clicks.
- Stop sending automated queries.
- Search like a human.
- Check for malware and browser extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the websites have a barrier for preventing automated test software from signing in or even browsing through them, and since Selenium is just a automated web testing tool you are debarred from signing in, one of the ways to fix it, is by using pyautogui for just the basic sign in and then carry forwarding with your selenium code, or maybe using API for the particular google service which you require.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the user is authorized under the google account, it does not protect him from the fact that at any site or his request captcha, because the whole point is that and determine who the bot and who a man ... The only solution how to bypass captchas is to use a service to recognize such captchas and solve them automatically